# Linking from a subfolder back to the root folder index.html file

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am having trouble linking from a subfolder index file back to my root folder index file.

I have a logo in the nav bar of example.com/blog that I would like to have link back to example.com

I have tested various linking options for the logo image including

```
<a href="../index.html">
<a href="http://www.example.com">
<a href="../">
```

And none of them seem to work. The logo image continues to link to example.com/blog/index.html

The strange thing is that if I right click on the image and then select open in a new window/tab, then it will load example.com just fine.

I am at a complete loss.

Could this be something related to my .htaccess file?

**Additional Info**

I added a "Home" text link to the nav bar using the below syntax and it works perfectly.

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Home</a>
```

The image for some reason will not link back to the rootfolder index.html file using the same syntax. It keeps loading http://www.example.com/blog/index.html

Comment: Can you add any error messages that you are getting

Comment: Could you try using javascript

Comment: you want link to images path in .htaccess file ?

Comment: @Biswajit_86 The only error message I am receiving on the page is jquery related.  (Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression) Not sure if this is related to the issue I am having however.

Comment: @daremachine No I am trying to get the image in my nav bar to act as a "go to home" button however the link will not redirect to the index.html file in my rootfolder for some reason.

Comment: and you have a htaccess? i ask for it because it can do bad redirect

Comment: @daremachine yes I do have a .htaccess file

Answer (score 0):

Try using a javascript redirect

```js
function home() {
  window.location.replace("http://example.com");
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="home()">hi</button>
```

Replace http://example.com with your website.

Comment: it is not always good. If javascript had error then all links in page are inactive

Comment: I would prefer to find a solution that wasn't javascript based